# Google JSON API and GQL. Get objects by date range

Tags: node.js, google-api, gql, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-nodejs-client

I try to find objects in google datastore via GQL and JSON API by date range.
For example, this is my request:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE uuid = "test" AND start >= 100 AND end <= 150
```

But i get error:

```
{ errors: 
  [ { domain: 'global',
   reason: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
   message: 'can\'t have inequality filters on different properties: [start, end]' } ],
  code: 400,
  message: 'can\'t have inequality filters on different properties: [start, end]' }
```

Can i edit this request or use another way to get objects by date range?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Availability date range queries in app engine datastore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319489/availability-date-range-queries-in-app-engine-datastore)

Comment: No, i use nodejs and JSON API.

Comment: Cloud Datastore is backed by the same implementation and only supports inequality filters on a single property:
https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#Datastore_Inequality_filters_are_limited_to_at_most_one_property

Answer (score 0):

You have two inequality statements in a single query which isn't supported by datastore/gql.

"start >= 100 AND end <= 150"

You could have 
"start >= 100 AND start <=150"

but not both start and end.

One solution is you need to set just one inequality in your GQL query and filter the results manually for the second inequality.