# Query to get all dates between 2 given dates

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to get all dates between 2 given dates from a datastore (appengine), I found this query that gives the ascending and descending dates but I need what is between

```
Query q = new Query("Employee Attendance Sheet test1").addSort("Date", Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING);
```

If there is somehow to mix an ascending and descending queries maybe

I found these codes also

```
query.setFilter("dateField < dateParam");
```

but the setFilter function is telling me that it does not accept string. What is wrong ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Availability date range queries in app engine datastore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319489/availability-date-range-queries-in-app-engine-datastore)

Comment: So you have a one date field `dateField` and you would like find all entities that have this date field between two dates?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only **one** date field that you would like to check if it falls into a time period (between two given dates), than you can simply use query with composite filter:

```
Filter startDateFilter = new FilterPredicate("dateField",
                         FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
                         startDate);

Filter endDateFilter = new FilterPredicate("dateField",
                       FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
                       endDate);

Filter dateFilter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(startDateFilter, endDateFilter);

Query q = new Query("EntityName").setFilter(dateFilter);
```

Comment: i have already tried .. it gives a servlet error .. the startDate and endDate shoult be of type Date right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to query by dates then you need to save them as `Date`.

Comment: thank you Peter  for your response .. the problem was not in the query itself.. what you suggested was useful .. regards